Using Cython and PyInstaller with custom module and folders
I have the following folder architecture (There are more files/folders, just here for the sake of example):
main.py
utils/
| utils1.py
| utils2.py
module/
| __init__.py
| __main__.py
| subfolder1/
| | __init__.py
| | subsubfolder1/
| | | __init__.py
| | | file1.py

When i run it through the console, it works as expected, so next step is to make an executable out from it (running on VM LUbuntu 22_04), so using Cython + PyInstaller.
For the Cython part, I created a setup.py file, looking for all the .py files, and Cythonizing all of them (called with option "develop"):
from setuptool import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from glob import glob

module_list = glob("utils/*.py")
module_list.extend(glob("module/**/*.py", recursive=True))

setup(scripts=glob("main.py"),
      ext_modules=cythonize(module_list, exclude="*/__*__.py", force=True))

First point at this stage, the module generated .so files are scattered across the project, some at the top level, others at the attached file level.
Now I use PyInstaller, basically using the following command in a bash file:
pyinstaller --onefile -r FILE.so,dll,FILE.so {for each generated .so file} --name project_name ./main.py

The generation runs fine, but when i run it, i have an error:
ModuleNotFoundError: module file1 not found
I tried using relative paths and file name only for the so files, but still the same error.
I also tried to set the --onedir option, to see if anything is missing, but it looked fine as i wandered in the generated folder.
I looked at the warnproject file, and there is a whole bunch of missing imports.
I tried to force the import, using the option --hidden-import file1 (Both relative path and module name), but it didn't work.
Something else i don't understand, I copied both Cython and PyInstaller configuration/codes from another, where there are also some utils folders, but no module. All the .so files were generated at the project top level. Does it change something in the way it must be configured ?
